# How can I make an instantiation random?

Tags: unity, random

I'm trying to do it so when I have an instantiated an item upon the game starting, it is random as to whether it actually instantiates or not. Here's the code I have so far:

```
public GameObject anyItem;
void Start()
{
    Instantiate(anyItem, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(anyItem, new Vector3(11, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

How can I do it so these items (individually, not both together) are decided randomly as to whether they will actually be instantiated or not?

Comment: Can you further explain what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to assign a certain probability as to whether an object gets instantiated?

Comment: Yes! Precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Random.Range(0, 100)` to get a random int from 0 to 100 for example.  You then just need a probability for each GameObject you're trying to instantiate.

```
public GameObject anyItem;

void Start()
{
    // There is a 60% chance for a new object
    randomlyInstantiateAtPosition(60, new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    // There is a 25% chance for a new object
    randomlyInstantiateAtPosition(25, new Vector3(11, 0, 0));
    // This one will always be made
    randomlyInstantiateAtPosition(100, new Vector3(22, 0, 0));
}

private void randomlyInstantiateAtPosition(int probability, Vector3 position) {
    if (Random.Range(0, 100) < probability) {
        Instantiate(anyItem, position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Here's the documentation for `Random.Range`:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: For more information on how to elegantly implement weighted probabilities: [How do I create a weighted collection and then pick a random element from it?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162976/how-do-i-create-a-weighted-collection-and-then-pick-a-random-element-from-it)

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I second looking at what @Philipp commented; it's not particularly fun to maintain hardcoded magic numbers.