# Balancing random chance

Tags: game-design, algorithm, balance

I'm working on a text-based RPG incremental/clicker game. One of the features I'd like to implement is a 'bloodline' system; Every user gets a one time random chance to 'roll' for a bloodline. Bloodlines can give benefits/passive improvements to a user; increase HP by 10, increase mana by 10, etc, depending on how good/rare the bloodline is. Bloodlines are divided in tiers: S-rank, A-rank, B-rank, C-rank and D-rank.

Im unsure however on how to technically implement and more importantly balance this. The most straightforward way seems to be to just do a diceroll, for example (pseudocode):

```js
let tier;
/** roll a thousand sided die */
const roll = rollD1000(); 

if(roll === 1000) {
  tier = 'S';
}

if(roll < 1000 && > 900) {
  tier = 'A';
}

// etc
```

But then how should I balance it? For example, I want the S-tier to be very rare, but not impossible to roll. How would I find a good 'scale'? Are there any examples of balancing something like this out there?

Comment: We already have a question about how to do the technical implementation: [How do I create a weighted collection and then pick a random element from it?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162976/how-do-i-create-a-weighted-collection-and-then-pick-a-random-element-from-it)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, but wasnt able to find it myself

Comment: Regarding your question about how to balance this: I think you are not providing nearly enough information for us to help you with that. At first glance the whole system feels unfair by design, because you are giving players advantages and disadvantages based on a random number roll. This appears to be intentional for some reason. How unfair do you want it to be? That's up to you.

Comment: When the random event is one that can happen to a player multiple times, we can use expected value to balance the rarer options against the common ones. Multiply the utility value of each outcome by its probability of occurring and you get the expected value due to that outcome. The sum of all those values is the expected utility to the player of one attempt/roll. Players who get lucky and get the better outcome get more utility in the short run, but over many trials their net utility converges toward the expectation. But as Philipp points out, this doesn't work when players get one roll ever.